# Listing files in a directory that do not end with vXXX

Tags: bash

I have a directory with a list of files like so:

```
  1.html
  1.html.v1
  1.html.v2
  2.html
  2.html.v1
  a.pdf
  a.pdf.v1
  b.pdf
  b.pdf.v1
  b.pdf.v2
```

In bash, how can I list all the files that do not end with a .v[Number]?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep -v` to filter away the `.v[0-9]*` stuff:

```
ls | grep -v ".v[0-9]*$"
```

For your example this gives

```
1.html
2.html
a.pdf
b.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

With bash only:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls !(*.v[0-9])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to do it by filtering out unwanted results - [@Jonas Heidelberg's Answer (below)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969408/listing-files-in-a-directory-that-do-not-end-with-vxxx/7969473#7969473) is the best method for that **BUT** I personally find that listing all the files you **do** want to show is often quicker.

`ls *.v[#]` - where `#` is the number you ***do*** want to display will do this:

```
# All files
[ 09:20 Jonathan@MacBookPro ~ ]$ ls -l *.v*
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonathan  staff     0B Nov  1 09:20 a.v1
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonathan  staff     0B Nov  1 09:20 b.v2
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonathan  staff     0B Nov  1 09:20 c.v3

# Filtered
[ 09:20 Jonathan@MacBookPro ~ ]$ ls -l *.v[23]
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonathan  staff     0B Nov  1 09:20 b.v2
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonathan  staff     0B Nov  1 09:20 c.v3
[ 09:20 Jonathan@MacBookPro ~ ]$ ls -l *.v[13]
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonathan  staff     0B Nov  1 09:20 a.v1
-rw-r--r--  1 Jonathan  staff     0B Nov  1 09:20 c.v3
```

Comment: The OP says "list all the files that do **not** end with a .v[Number]" (emphasis mine)...

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg Hence why I included a qualifier pointing to your answer =)