# How to write "No file ends with" a user-defined extension

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering if there was a way to tell the user that no file in a directory they specified has the file extension they are looking for. The only way I could think of uses an if/else, but would be tripped up if any other file extension exists in the directory. I was able to find something but it was bash: [Listing files in a directory that do not end with vXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969408/listing-files-in-a-directory-that-do-not-end-with-vxxx) and not exactly what I was looking for.

Here is an example of a directory:

```
out-30000000.txt.processed
out-31000000.txt.processed
out-32000000.txt.processed
out-33000000.txt.processed
out-34000000.txt.processed
nope.csv
```

If I use the following code:

```
def folder_location():
    location = raw_input("What is the folder containing the data you like processed located? ")
    #location = "C:/Code/Samples/Dates/2015-06-07/Large-Scale Data Parsing/Data Files"
    if os.path.exists(location) == True: #Tests to see if user entered a valid path
        print "You entered:",location
        if raw_input("Is this correct? Use 'Y' or 'N' to answer. ") == "Y":
            print ""
            file_extension(location)
        else:
            folder_location()
    else:
        print "I'm sorry, but the file location you have entered does not exist. Please try again."
        folder_location()

def file_extension(location):
    file_extension = raw_input("What is the file type (.txt for example)? ")
    print "You entered:", file_extension
    if raw_input("Is this correct? Use 'Y' or 'N' to answer. ") == "Y":
        print ""
        each_file(location, file_extension)
    else:
        file_extension(location)

def each_file(location, file_extension):
    try:
        column = (raw_input("Please enter column name you want to analyze: ")) #Using smcn
        print "You entered:",column
        if raw_input("Is this correct? Use 'Y' and 'N' to answer. ") == "Y":
            print ""
            sort_by(location,file_extension,column)
        else:
            each_file(location,file_extension)
    except TypeError:
        print "That is not a valid column name. Please try again."
        each_file(location,file_extension)

def sort_by(location, file_extension, column):
    content = os.listdir(location)
    for item in content:
        if item.endswith(file_extension):
            data = csv.reader(open(os.path.join(location,item)),delimiter=',')
            col_position = get_columnposition(data.next(),column)
            to_count = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(col_position))
            count_date(to_count, location)
        else:
            print "No file in this directory ends with " + file_extension
```

I get:

```
No file in this directory ends with .processed
```

and then the rest of my output (code not posted here).

Is there a way for me to say (I'm going to put it in a code block just to show how it works in my mind):

```
def file_extension(location):
    file_extension = raw_input("What is the file type (.txt for example)? ")
    print "You entered:", file_extension
    if raw_input("Is this correct? Use 'Y' or 'N' to answer. ") == "Y":
        print ""
        each_file(location, file_extension)
    else:
        file_extension(location)

def each_file(location, file_extension):
    try:
        column = (raw_input("Please enter column name you want to analyze: ")) #Using smcn
        print "You entered:",column
        if raw_input("Is this correct? Use 'Y' and 'N' to answer. ") == "Y":
            print ""
            sort_by(location,file_extension,column)
        else:
            each_file(location,file_extension)
    except TypeError:
        print "That is not a valid column name. Please try again."
        each_file(location,file_extension)

def sort_by(location, file_extension, column):
    content = os.listdir(location)
    for item in content:
        if item.endswith(file_extension):
            data = csv.reader(open(os.path.join(location,item)),delimiter=',')
            col_position = get_columnposition(data.next(),column)
            to_count = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(col_position))
            count_date(to_count, location)
        if no item.endswith(file_extension):
            print "No file in this directory ends with " + file_extension
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If it would help, I could edit in the rest of my code I have at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: @Al G I didn't realize I was supposed to format a directory like code and not put the language tag in the tittle. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic should be the following:

1. Ask for the directory
2. Ask for the extension
3. Check if any file ends with that extension
4. If there is at least one file, then ask for the column

To make all this easier, use `csv` and `glob`:

```
import glob
import csv
import os

directory = input('Please enter the directory: ')
extension = input('Please enter the extension (.txt, .csv): ')
files = list(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, extension)))
if not files:
   print('Sorry, no files match your extension {} in the directory {}'.
         format(extension, directory))
else:
    for file_name in files:
        col = input('Enter the column number for {}'.format(file_name))
        with open(file_name, 'r') as thefile:
            reader = csv.reader(thefile, delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
                try:
                    do_something(row[col])
                except IndexError:
                    print('Column {} does not exist'.format(col))
```

Comment: Thanks for the logic path and use of code! I'm using your logic path now, but not the exact code so I can still learn and not just copy.